# Партиции в обратном порядке

Tags: oracle, plsql, insert, partition, interval

Создана партиционированная таблица с автоматическим созданием партиций (диапазон, интервал - 1, ключ число)

```
partition by range (gr_id)
interval (1)
(
  partition v_less_1 values less than (1)
)
enable row movement
```

Если вставлять сначала записи с gr_id = 4, то создается партиция с high_value = 5. И если потом добавлять записи с gr_id = 2, то они уходят в эту партицию, партиция с high_value = 3 не создается. И это логично.

Но если мне надо разграничить по партициям при именно таком порядке вставки, то как быть? Могу ли я в этом случае использовать автоматическое создание партиций или придется жестко прописывать все партиции для одиночных значений?

Comment: partition by list automatic?

Comment: У вас всё должно работать. Создайте воиспроизводимый пример на каком-то фиддле и дайте ссылку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня не получилось воспроизвести этот эффект. Может быть, Вы что-то забыли указать.

```sql
SELECT * 
  FROM v$version;

> Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit
> Production PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
> "CORE 11.2.0.4.0  Production" TNS for Linux: Version 11.2.0.4.0 -
> Production NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production

CREATE TABLE cats
(cat_id        NUMBER,
 cat_name      VARCHAR2(50),
 cat_color     VARCHAR2(100),
 qty_of_limbs  NUMBER)
PARTITION BY RANGE (qty_of_limbs) INTERVAL (1)
(PARTITION v_less_1  VALUES LESS THAN (1));

-- результат выборки приводится после каждой команды insert
SELECT partition_name, high_value, partition_position
  FROM user_tab_partitions 
 WHERE table_name = 'CATS';

> V_LESS_1   1  1

insert into cats VALUES (1, 'Ктулха', 'зелёный', 18);

> V_LESS_1   1  1
> SYS_P30384 19 2

insert into cats VALUES (2, 'Петя', 'чёрный', 2);

V_LESS_1    1   1
SYS_P30385  3   2
SYS_P30384  19  3

insert into cats VALUES (3, 'Котопёс', 'чёрный', 2.5);

V_LESS_1    1   1
SYS_P30385  3   2
SYS_P30384  19  3
```

Тем не менее, в версии `12.2` добавили автоматическое секционирование по списку. Поскольку у вас интервал 1, и, наверное, имеются в виду целочисленные значения, то должно подойти.

```sql
CREATE TABLE cats
(cat_id        NUMBER,
 cat_name      VARCHAR2(50),
 cat_color     VARCHAR2(100),
 qty_of_limbs  NUMBER)
PARTITION BY LIST (qty_of_limbs) AUTOMATIC
(PARTITION p_default VALUES (4));

insert into cats VALUES (1, 'Вася', 'чёрный', 4);
insert into cats VALUES (2, 'Петя', 'чёрный', 3);
insert into cats VALUES (3, 'Котопёс', 'жёлтый', 3.5);
```

Comment: К сожалению версия Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
"CORE 11.2.0.4.0 Production"
TNS for Linux: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production

Comment: Может есть вариант для 11g?

Comment: У меня даже не получается воспроизвести Ваш пример. Новые секции создаются даже если вставлять 5 и 3 последовательно на версии 11.2